# Truecaller_sdk not working in release appbundle

Tags: java, android

I added truecaller login for phone number verification I installed its working fine in the signed release apk if I generate a signed app bundle it's not working its calling `onfailuerLister()` error code 3 partnerKey error, it working fine if I have taken debug SHA1 if it's working in debug apk but not working in debug app-bundle, if I have taken SHA1 from release then release apk working fine but not working in the release app bundle, totally app-bundle not working at all, all other feature like location everything working fine in app-bundle except truecaller login

Mainactivity.java

```
package com.amitor.kotlintrue;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.truecaller.android.sdk.ITrueCallback;
import com.truecaller.android.sdk.TrueError;
import com.truecaller.android.sdk.TrueProfile;
import com.truecaller.android.sdk.TruecallerSDK;
import com.truecaller.android.sdk.TruecallerSdkScope;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
EditText editTextName, mobileNumber;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextName = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        mobileNumber = findViewById(R.id.mobileNumberText);

        (findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
            //check if TrueCaller SDk is usable
            if(TruecallerSDK.getInstance().isUsable()){
                TruecallerSDK.getInstance().getUserProfile(this);
            }else{

                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dialogBuilder.setMessage("Truecaller App not installed.");

                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Closing dialog");

                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                );

                dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
                dialogBuilder.setTitle(" ");

                AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        // customisation of TrueCaller function like color , text can be done here
        TruecallerSdkScope trueScope = new TruecallerSdkScope.Builder(this, sdkCallback)
                .consentMode(TruecallerSdkScope.CONSENT_MODE_BOTTOMSHEET)
                .loginTextPrefix(TruecallerSdkScope.LOGIN_TEXT_PREFIX_TO_GET_STARTED)
                .loginTextSuffix(TruecallerSdkScope.LOGIN_TEXT_SUFFIX_PLEASE_VERIFY_MOBILE_NO)
                .ctaTextPrefix(TruecallerSdkScope.CTA_TEXT_PREFIX_USE)
                .buttonShapeOptions(TruecallerSdkScope.BUTTON_SHAPE_ROUNDED)
                .privacyPolicyUrl("https://tagle.in")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("https://tagle.in")
                .footerType(TruecallerSdkScope.FOOTER_TYPE_NONE)
                .consentTitleOption(TruecallerSdkScope.SDK_CONSENT_TITLE_LOG_IN)
                .build();
        TruecallerSDK.init(trueScope);
    }
    private final ITrueCallback sdkCallback = new ITrueCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccessProfileShared(@NonNull final TrueProfile trueProfile) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,trueProfile.firstName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            Log.i(TAG, trueProfile.firstName + " " + trueProfile.lastName);
            launchHome(trueProfile);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailureProfileShared(@NonNull final TrueError trueError) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,TrueError.ERROR_TYPE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
//            Log.i(TAG, trueError.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationRequired(@Nullable final TrueError trueError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,trueError.getErrorType(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            Log.i(TAG, "onVerificationRequired");
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == TruecallerSDK.SHARE_PROFILE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            TruecallerSDK.getInstance().onActivityResultObtained(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }    }

    private void launchHome(TrueProfile trueProfile) {

        editTextName.setText(trueProfile.firstName);
        mobileNumber.setText(trueProfile.phoneNumber);

//        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class)
//                .putExtra("profile", trueProfile));
//        finish();
    }

}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('/Users/moden/key_store.jks')
            storePassword '189556'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword '189556'
        }

        release {
            storeFile file('/Users/moden/key_store.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword '123456'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.amitor.kotlintrue'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amitor.kotlintrue"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.truecaller.android.sdk:truecaller-sdk:2.7.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.truecaller.android.sdk" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Kotlintrue"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.truecaller.android.sdk.PartnerKey"
            android:value="3sBRy9fe254fbac0541b5988fb6b085190ed4" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I changed many partners kyes changed dependency I tried every  solution which I got but not working at all

Comment: @Irshan Programmer How you are testing your app bundle ?

Comment: In the beginning, I used to publish app in the play store after the app was live then I was checking by changing the version code after 3 to 4 times truecaller was not working then I downloaded the app from the play store app bundle installer, from this app I'm checking my appbundle

Comment: while using bundle tool are you signing your apk with your keystore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your bundle tool to create an apk for testing then you can use the following command to generate a universal apk.

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=<bundle_file_location> --output=universal.apks --mode=universal --ks=<keystore_name> --ks-pass='pass:<keystore_passowrd>' --ks-key-alias=<keystore_alias_name> --key-pass='pass:key_password'
```

Then extract the apk using following command

```
unzip universal.apks -d apks
```

For playstore apps you have to update your SHA-1 with the SHA-1 from playstore App Integrity --> App Signing tab in truecaller page.

Comment: I created universal.apk from the app bundle here also the same universal.apk is working fine truecaller is working. but the  appbundle  which is I have taken that was published on the playstore that appbundle not working, apk which was created from this appbundle working fine  here is the command which I used to create the apk java -jar bundletool.jar build-apks --bundle=app-release.aab --output=app.apks --ks=key_store.jks --ks-pass=pass:123456 --ks-key-alias=key0 --key-pass=pass:123456 --overwrite --mode=universal

Comment: error is : error code 2 invalid partner credential

Comment: --ks-pass=pass:123456 this should be --ks-pass='pass:123456' and  --key-pass=pass:123456 this should be --key-pass='pass:123456'. Add single quotes

Comment: In the playstore have you updated the SHA1 from App Integrity in truecaller project page ?

Comment: @Irshad Programmer Firstly Don't expose these keys publicly the fingerprint should be SHA1 of upload key

Comment: Fingerprint which I used is SHA1 release only

Comment: It doesnt seem like that you have given alphanumeric number . It should be a colon separated  string.

Comment: in develper.truecaller.com we add the sha1 fingerprint key with Colen separated once we click on the update application button then it will generate appkey and that will remove all the Colen

Comment: Ok Have you tried the SHA1 of the App signing key ?

Comment: yes, my key_store.jks which I'm using to build appbundle and release apk that also generates the same SHA1 key only I'm using it everywhere

Comment: can you please try this one just create a simple android project using the above code then you will get to know

Answer (score 0):

So Truecaller SDK gets a bit tricky when you are generating bundles. Let's say you have a current Truecaller key which you have made for your release/debug builds and when you run the application it runs fine but when you make a bundle (.aab) of it, it doesn't work.

Let's see how to fix this :

If you read the Truecaller SDK docs carefully ( Link - https://docs.truecaller.com/truecaller-sdk/android/getting-release-ready/google-play-app-signing )

you will find that you would need to create a new Truecaller Partner key but this time with the SHA1 from your Google Play console.

**Steps:**

1. Go to your app on Play console.
2. Find out the SHA1 of your app generated by Play Console ( It's different from the one you provided via Android Studio )
3. Use that SHA1 to generate a new Truecaller Partner key
4. Use this partner key when you are making bundles for releasing on Play Store.
5. If you want to directly install on your device this key won't work so you will have to use your previous key only.

Tip : You can keep both the keys in your strings.xml and use the key generated via SHA1 from Play Console when you are making bundles otherwise use your normal key for debugging.